# Insert JSON object into database

Tags: asp.net, sql, json

Hi i have a set of record with below format (the item ID is not in the format "key" : "value" and it consists thousand of records)

```
{
   "items":[
    {
        "20057":{
             "name":"Name 20057",
             "item_name":"name_20057"
        }
    },
    {
    "20060":{
         "name":"Name 20060",
         "item_name":"name_20060"
        }
     }
   ]
}
```

and i need to insert all of them into database as below

```
ItemID | Name       | Item_Name
----------------------------------
20057  | Name 20057 | name_20057
20060  | Name 20060 | name_20060
```

Is there any way to do this using SQL query or ASP.NET?

UPDATE

I tried to do it with .net and deserialize it. But i failed get the ItemID since it is not in this format "key" : "value"

Comment: I suggest doing it with .net code.

Comment: Use JSON.Net, deserialize the text to class/objects and push that object to database

Comment: I agree with Dan use something like JSON.NET to Dapper to get the data into the DB.

Comment: I tried to do it with .net and deserialize it. but i cannot get the ItemID since it is not in this format "key" : "value"

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. Deserialize  json into .Net Objects and then insert into DB.

In order to write an example ,  [I used JSON.NET library.](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
 private void TestJson()
        {
            string json = @"{'items':[
    {
        '20057':{
             'name':'Name 20057',
             'item_name':'name_20057'
        }
    },
    {
    '20060':{
         'name':'Name 20060',
         'item_name':'name_20060'
        }
     }

   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer jsonObj = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
}
```

And than you can iterate using SelectToken or Path methods

1. Create store procedure which will receive JSON string. In store procedure, convert it into table, and insert into DB.

   [Example how to convert json string into table](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I tried to do it with .net and deserialize it. but i cannot get the ItemID since it is not in this format "key" : "value"

Answer (score 0):

If you could get your json to the below format things would be a little bit easier when it comes to using json.net library:

```
[
    {
        "ItemID": 20057,
        "name": "Name 20057",
        "item_name": "name_20057"
    },
    {
        "ItemID": 20060,
        "name": "Name 20060",
        "item_name": "name_20060"
    }
]
```

You'll need a c# class as follows:

```
public class ItemDetail
{
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally you can call the following method to get the array:

```
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemDetail>>(json)
```

Comment: I cannot change the json format as it consists of thousand of records. Or is there any can i can convert it into the format above?

Comment: We can write custom converters for the job using the library. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/145682